# code optimising for if-else function

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to write a partition function.
The output values are obtained by comparing the values of input dx and dy.
The below code run very slow. Any suggestion to speedup the code?

I search the web, it seems that using lookup table or SSE instructions is 
possible. But I little idea in implementing them.

Thank you very much.

```
inline int fastatan2( 
    int dy,
    int dx
) {    
    if(dy<0) { dx *= -1; dy *= -1; }   
    if( dx > 0 ){ 
        if( dy <  dx ) return (dy <= ((  17560*dx)>>16))? 0:1;
        else           return (dy <= (( 244583*dx)>>16))? 2:3; 
    }else{ 
        if( dy < -dx ) return (dy <= (( -17560*dx)>>16))? 0:5;
        else           return (dy <= ((-244583*dx)>>16))? 4:3;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: How did you measure? I don't believe this is the bottleneck in your code actually.

Comment: The first optimization is to indent your code.

Comment: Did you measured branch misses count with profiler? DId you even run the profiler? If so, it would be good to provide results.

Comment: What are those magic numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer.
First remove all the branches and then implement as SSE.
I haven't check the speed yet.

```
const int T1    =  17560;
const int T2    = 244583;
const int SHIFT = 16;

int A = 2*((dx ^ dy) >= 0)-1;  //check (dy,dx) opposite sign  
dy    = abs(dy); 
dx    = abs(dx); 

int B1 = (dy < dx);
int B2 = (dy > ((T1*dx) >> SHIFT));
int B3 = (dx > ((T1*dy) >> SHIFT));

const int table1[]={3,2,3,2,0,0,1,1};
int ori = table1[B3 + B2*2 + B1*4]; //implement as bit shuffle (_mm_shuffle_epi8)


const int table2[]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ori = table2[A*ori + 6];   //implement as bit shuffle (_mm_shuffle_epi8)

return ori;
```

The code above is a fast quantization of angle shown below.
There are some differences at (dx==0, dy==0) and boundary cases (abs(dx)==abs(dy), at angle 45, 135 degrees).

```
int exact_atan2(
    int dx,
    int dy
){
    float angle = atan2((float)dy, (float)dx) / 3.14159265359f * 180.f;
    float o = (angle + 360.f) / (180.f / 6) ; 
    int ori = int(o+0.5)%6;   
    return ori;
}
```